# How to get the selected rows in ASPxGridView?

Tags: asp.net, devexpress, aspxgridview

I have a grid with `ASPxCheckBox` in `Data Item Template`. How to get `KeyFieldValue` of all rows whose checkbox is checked. I am trying to do this using client-side code and do it for whole grid not on visible index. Is it possible?

Note: I cannot use simple row selection command column as I am using it for some other purpose.

Comment: Have you look at documentation? http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebASPxGridViewScriptsASPxClientGridViewClassMethodsTopic

Comment: yes, I have checked the documentation. Have I missed something init? I didn't find anything init.

Comment: There are samples that could help you with this: [1](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Example/Details/E1559), [2](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Example/Details/E1559) , [3](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q527992).

Answer (score 0):

if you dontuse  client-side code, you should use detailrow in aspxgridview. And you must use beforeperformdataselect event. if you really need checkbox, you can add checkbox a new field in asapxgridview.